# R: regex from first character to the end of the string

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like these here:

```
a <- "-en eller -et eller (uofficielt) -'en eller (uofficielt) -'et"
b <- "-ten, -ter, -terne"
```

And I would like to use regular expressions in R to extract the text from the "-" to the first non-character, thus get:

```
en et 'en 'et
ten ter terne
```

I have found a solution, but it just does not feel very satisfying or elegant

```
a <- unlist(strsplit(a, " |,"))
a <- a[grep("-", a)]
a <- gsub("-", "", a)

b <- unlist(strsplit(b, " |,"))
b <- b[grep("-", b)]
b <- gsub("-", "", b)
```

Do you have a suggesting for a more elegant one-liner that extracts all the endings I want?

Comment: What is a "non-character" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to match a `-` that is not preceded with a word char (that is, not match when it is part of a compound word), and there is an optional `'` after the hyphen, that is then followed with 1+ word chars. Then, you can use

```
a <- "-en eller -et eller (uofficielt) -'en eller (uofficielt) -'et"
b <- "-ten, -ter, -terne"
pat <- "\\B-\\K'?\\w+"
res_a <- regmatches(a, gregexpr(pat, a, perl=TRUE))
unlist(res_a)
## [1] "en"  "et"  "'en" "'et"
res_b <- regmatches(b, gregexpr(pat, b, perl=TRUE))
unlist(res_b)
## [1] "ten"   "ter"   "terne"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/dH00Go)

**Pattern details**:

- `\\B` - a non-word boundary
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\\K` - match reset operator
- `'?` - an optional `'`
- `\\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or `_`

Comment: If there must be a space/start of string before a `-`, then replace `\\B` with `(?<!\\S)`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explaination. I usually only use regex for simpler operations, so it is nice to understand how more complex operations work.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(a, '(?<=-)[^, ]+')[[1]]
#[1] "en"  "et"  "'en" "'et"


str_extract_all(b, '(?<=-)[^, ]+')[[1]]
#[1] "ten"   "ter"   "terne"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it in base R, I do not not think you will get it much more elegant that what you have (and you can always make that a one-liner). The `value` argument of grep might help you a bit as below.

Maybe

```
substring(grep("-'?\\w", strsplit(a, " ")[[1]], value = TRUE), 2)
```

or

```
gsub("-", "", grep("-'?\\w", strsplit(a, " ")[[1]], value = TRUE)
```

can be considered *slightly* more elegant.